# How to get IBM MobileFirst getting-started-7.1 docs in pdf form for offline Learning.

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to get all docs related to IBM MobileFirst 7.1 training for offline learning. As of now I could find all documentation at https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/ for online learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

All tutorials are also converted to PDF format and are stored in the Developer Center's GitHub page. A link is available at the bottom of this page: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/

Here's a direct download link to the .zip file containing all of the tutorials: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/TutorialsForOfflineReading/archive/release71.zip